# Plotting GPS data in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gps

I'm looking for ways to plot GPS coordinates in Python. I want to be able to create a map that traces a GPS in a racing car on a track, and shows the amount of throttle during different parts of the track. I've attached an image that shows something similar to what I want.

The program is written in Python 2.7, and uses the QT library.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9MJs.png)

Comment: Show what you have so far, so others can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very vague, however a starting point might be the following: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html MatPlotLib is a very popular Python plotting library.

Comment: That looks great! Do you have any experience with it, if it's easy to use etc?

Comment: I've only ever used it in a very basic way (plotting x/y coordinates) and it didn't take very long to configure. There are tons of examples of more complex uses out there.